# Android volley sending data twice

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using **Volley** Network Library in my application.

**The Issue is that it is sending  data more than once when network connection is slow.**

And After I Google this issue, all i can find about this issue is below point:

```
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

But I am not able to edit my volley library Hurlkstack classes.

It says:

The jar of this class file belong to container android Private libraries which does not allow modification to source attachments on it entries.

What should i do can some one help me

i have the following code where should i modify
.

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            "http://example.com/***.php", obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        response.getString("success");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027995/android-volley-returning-results-twice-for-one-request

Comment: Can you post how you post your data?? because i can just see the code for retrieve data using `JsonObjectRequest`. You can set retry policy for that `jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                       0,
                       DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                       DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Comment: @PiyushGupta i have got answer if it did'nt satisfy me than i will post more info thanks for replying

Comment: @ShashikalaChavan Okay. no problem.

Comment: "DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 0" then also not working at my end

Answer (score 107, accepted):

No need to use `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);` to avoid [volley sending data twice](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/volley-users/8PE9dBbD6iA) bug. you need to set retry policy for current request :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(...);
jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                       0,
                       DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                       DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: @ShashikalaChavan: call `setRetryPolicy` before `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);` line

Comment: hey i got your answer and it was correct thanks for the help i just want to ask is there any way in volley to avoid data get lost during post data

Comment: Is this solution may cause `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException`? Is it possible? This is the problem ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40318347/4074312)) I've encountered after I used setRetryPolicy

Comment: if we set request timeout to zero then when it will timeout the request

Comment: To avoid sending twice, set maxNumRetries to 0. (DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 1 sot it will retry one time and send the message twice)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its also work on StringRequest

```
 stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

```

Comment: while thousands of people answering this, this thing never works

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but strangely for me only the
new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT) worked!
I ran tests on a Samsung-XCover Android 8.1.0 SDK-27 device.

Comment: Kotlin `request.setRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT))`,

or as mentioned set max retires to zero: `request.setRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT))`

Comment: Im wondering why the hell android is logging the request only being sent once, but the server showing 2 requests. Thank you very much OP

Comment: I am using it in string request  
`request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Answer (score 7):

Use below code after completion of **new Response.ErrorListener() method** in your volley parsing. Hope its useful for you. I faced same issue and resolved it with the same code.

Code:

```
jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
 RetryPolicy mRetryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(
 0,
 DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
 DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

 request.setRetryPolicy(mRetryPolicy);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this will definitely work.

```
 public <T> void addToRequestQueue(StringRequest req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem to use this code. Set **getCurrentRetryCount()** to **return 0** and Use HurlStack for BaseHttpStack.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NavigationActivity.this, new HurlStack());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest).setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 5000;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 0; //retry turn off
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

        }
    });
```

Hope this solve the problem.