# Volley RetryPolicy querying twice before timeout time is reached

Tags: android, android-volley

I have set a retry policy for volley. The query is being sent twice despite the the timeout period not being reached.

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(method, currentURL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    S.L("response: " + currentURL);
                    listener.onRequestExecuted("response", response, downloadId);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("CCC", "Error " + error.toString());                                             
                }
            })
```

This was the retry policy earlier

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 8000;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
            S.L("Retry error: " + error);
        }
    });
```

On SO there was another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873001/android-volley-sending-data-twice) pertaining to this. It appears to do so when volley detects a slow connection despite timeout period is not reached. Here the solution was to use a different retry policy:

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(8000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

This worked and is sending only a single query in the timeout period

Why is there a difference in behaviour between the retry policies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is there a difference in behaviour between the retry policies?

Because of the different `retry()` implementations.

From the source code of `DefaultRetryPolicy`:

```
@Override
public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
    mCurrentRetryCount++;
    mCurrentTimeoutMs += (mCurrentTimeoutMs * mBackoffMultiplier);
    if (!hasAttemptRemaining()) {
        throw error;
    }
}

protected boolean hasAttemptRemaining() {
    return mCurrentRetryCount <= mMaxNumRetries;
}
```

By passing `DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES` to the constructor, you're effectively setting `mMaxNumRetries` to `1`.

On the second retry `hasAttemptRemaining()` will return `false` and the `VolleyError` will be thrown.