# android Volley library NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: android, exception, android-volley, build.gradle

I'm getting this NegativeArraySizeException from Volley library. This error started after I changed Volley android-library-module to a maven dependencies like `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

I've this [singleton pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton) and I change the `addToRequestQueue` method to avoid double request bug with [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27873079/4074312):

```
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
```

I see that official Android-Volley does not getting any updates. So Do I have to change it back what it was? Or is there any way to fix this bug?
Thanks in advance.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -603989761
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:323)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:541)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:563)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:404)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:157)
       at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
```

Comment: Have you got the solution i'm getting the same issue @MiloRambaldi

Comment: Nope I haven't found any solution on this. Still using volley as a module in my project. That's working for me. @AshishPardhiye

Comment: This issue happens in xiomi devices

Comment: @AshishPardhiye not only in Xiaomi devices, it happens in Android-x86 too