# Android braintree paypal payment error Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I am implementing `braintree` in my android app.

The Credit or Debit Card payment is working fine.

Also the Paypal payment working fine, but I'm getting an error in the response.

Here is what I get, when I use `PayPal` payment.

```
Final Response: Braintree\Result\Error[errors=[Braintree\Error\ValidationErrorCollection/errors:[( )]], params=transaction=type=sale, amount=79, paymentMethodNonce=26333efd-40f6-00f4-5d9f-46353000f082, options=submitForSettlement=true, message=Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once., creditCardVerification=, transaction=, subscription=, merchantAccount=, verification=]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem and finally figured it out. The culprit was my Volley network API which i was using to submit the POST request and to call TransactionRequest on server side. When there is delay in response it submitted the request again. I made the retry option to '0' and everything fixed. How? check this [Android volley sending data twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873001/android-volley-sending-data-twice)

Answer (score 0):

> paymentMethodNonce=26333efd-40f6-00f4-5d9f-46353000f082

is Unique so try generating difference nonce and hit the api