# Android Volley Sending Multiple Requests

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

I am currently using Android Volley to send a POST request and get a Token from my server however when I look into it Volley is sending multiple requests which causes issues as my token refreshes whenever the page does. Is there any way to make Volley send only one request and then stop even if the request fails?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your issue got solved?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873001/android-volley-sending-data-twice) out.